# Why call "repaint()" instead of directly calling "paint(..)" in an Applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, repaint

We override paint method like this

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
   g.drawString(msg,xpos,ypos);
}
```

If we have another method lets say a mousepressed event method

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)    
    {
        xpos=me.getX();  // msg, xpos and ypos are variables of class
        ypos= me.getY();
        msg="You pressed mouse";
        repaint();
    }
```

Why cant we call paint`(Graphics g)` rather than `repaint()` ?

Comment: Short answer: because then it would be called at the wrong time or possibly in the wrong thread (and without an appropriate Graphics).

Comment: when we normally override it we just give the instance of graphics class nothing else so why inappropriate graphics ?0

Comment: The Graphics object must be prepared and delivered by the JVM itself with help from the platform/operating system. You can't just try to make one up on the spot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should probably try that.  You will notice

1. You will have to get the `Graphics` object `g` somehow.
2. Calling `paint` in the body of an event handler is not a best practice because it causes the body of that method to execute on the GUI thread right away, so no more events can be processed until `paint` returns.  OTOH, `repaint` schedules a paint event to occur at some convenient point in the future and does not make the GUI appear to hang.  Granted, in your case, `drawString` isn't terribly slow, but in general....

[Here is the classic article on painting](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html), from the Java people themselves.

Answer (score 9):

Calling repaint() doesn't necessarily immediately cause a call to paint().  It requests that a call be scheduled.

You should generally call repaint rather than paint so that the GUI framework can properly schedule the repainting.  It will do things like make sure paint gets called on the right thread, and has a chance to merge multiple calls to repaint if they happen before the framework gets around to doing the actual painting.

Calling repaint will be much more robust.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the scheduler - Also, because you would circumventing the scheduler, you'd probably end up with woeful performance, as the repaint manager is building up an idea of what needs to be updated, rather then updating the whole screen each time ;)